# how to use transit mode in google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Hey m working on gmap 2 . when i am using travlmode DRIVING that time i dint get proper time for travelling for public transport while  using TRANSIT Mode it gives proper time but i want to show all stops in between source and destination and wanted to use some images on gmap as a marker ?

Comment: Why you are working on google maps V2. it will be unavailable from May 19th 2013 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services

Comment: so what should i do ? and how i upgrade my code from version 2 to version 3

Comment: see this http://markus.tao.at/geo/google-maps-api-v3-is-in-town/